# How can I count the number of rows returned by a MySQL Query?

Tags: c#, mysql

Is there an easier way of doing this besides loading the data into a `DataTable` and using `Rows.Count` or using a `MySqlDataReader` and iterating through all the resulted rows?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

if you cant change the query easily

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (<your complete query here>)
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for! I tried using this command earlier but due to some reasons it did not work properly. Probably I missed something. Only as an add for those reading the question from now on , in order to work I had to add SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... AS some_name.:) Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You can execute a query like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the MySQL informational function [`FOUND_ROWS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/information-functions.html). Just run it immediately after your `SELECT` query. Like this:

```
SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
```

Answer (score 0):

Exec an

```
select count(*) from MyTable WHERE <clause>
```

and get the result with ExecuteScalar()